# Should all paint be removed before lining a wall?

Tags: walls

We recently had a wall painted (old style concrete then plastered wall), and although originally the paint stayed on for many years this time it has begun peeling within 2 months.

We are looking to line the walls with fiberliner and then paint on top of this - should all the underlying paint be scraped off first, or just that which is currently peeling?

Comment: Not sure what liner is.

Comment: Go back to the painter and make the painter fix it.  This is not your mistake. The painter owes you a properly done wall.

Comment: I would say yes,  Sounds like the prep work this time around was sub par. A dirty surface is one of the big reasons for paint to fail this quickly. Another possibility is frozen paint , when I see paint problems in winter I have found several times that pallets of paint froze and this affected the paint, the first time I discovered this there was another contractor checking on the paint by the time we were done a third had come in for the same problem and the store replaced all the paint but we still had to strip and repaint.

Comment: Please update your question to explain what “ Put liner on the wall“ means exactly.